# Listview is not showing the sd card data on options menu item click

Tags: android, listview, onclick, options-menu

On options menu Item click I want to show the files of emulator sd card in a list view.But Its not working for me.

my code is showing nothing on the options menu item click.

here is my code which I want to execute on options menu item click

Help is always appreciated.Thanks

```
             private void initUI() {
 ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
    mFileList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fileList);
    try {
                object = (ArrayList<FileMetaData>) reviewer
                .review("/mnt/sdcard/");
              for (FileMetaData s : object) {

                s.getName();
            System.out.println(s.getName());

              files.add(s.getName());
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.fileorfolder,
                    files);
            mFileList.setAdapter(adapter);

        }   


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            }
```

Comment: dont hardcord the path, Use, Environment.getExternalStorage() instead of that then try it

Comment: have you mentioned permissions to access sd card??

Comment: @kalyan pvs , I want to read the files from emulator sd card and want to display the same.  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> I HAVE GIVEN THESE PREMISSIONS

Comment: is your initUI() method is calling??

Comment: Kalyan I m calling this method on options menu item click

Comment: once debug your project check wheter the files are coming??and dont hardcode path..

Comment: Yes I should not hardcode the path, but its suggested for me to use this API 
     reviewer.review("/mnt/sdcard/");  and while debugging the control is first going to the line object = (ArrayList<FileMetaData>) reviewer
                .review("/mnt/sdcard/"); and coming next to the catch block. I dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory();
String[] files = path.list();
```

You now have a String array of the files and subdirectories.